# How to escape '%' inside varchar @params for RAISERROR funcion in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiserror

How I should escape the `%` character in params so my `RAISERROR` retun my message

```
declare @msg varchar(max)  = (SELECT ' Message with %  ' AS MSG)

if @msg is not null
begin
    RAISERROR (@msg ,16,1); 
end
```

This will rise error with message

> Msg 2787, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid format specification: '%  '.

For end users this message is unreadable.

My messages is generated from database and setting this message.

Way I do avoid getting wrong message is replacing

```
set @msg = REPLACE(@msg,'%','P')
```

But I still do not know how to add `%` sign

Answer (score 22):

Use `%%`:

```
raiserror(N'This is a message with %%', 0, 1);
```

Comment: In that way I still need to do replace, Can I avoid using replace ?

Comment: Store `%%` in the database too, where the message comes from.

Comment: Works with [`FORMATMESSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql) as well

Answer (score 11):

There's a simple, neat way to work around the percentage sign problem. Use the message text as parameter:

`RAISERROR ('%s', 16, 1, 'Message with %')`

Answer (score 4):

As you are using SQL 2012, you could ([should?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(RAISERROR_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)) be using the new THROW syntax, eg

```
BEGIN TRY

    RAISERROR ( 'dummy', 16, 1 )

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(2048) = ( SELECT 'Message with %% ' AS MSG );

    THROW 51000, @msg, 1;

END CATCH
```

Although THROW doesn't like percentage signs (%) either so you still have to escape it, presumably because you can use FORMATMESSAGE with it.  % signs on their own cause a headache for FORMATMESSAGE too as they're basically placeholders for parameters you pass in.  So my honest advice would be to simply use the 'percent' word instead:

```
USE tempdb

EXEC sys.sp_addmessage
      @msgnum   = 60001
    , @severity = 16
    , @msgtext  = N'I am 99.99999% this will NOT work.' -- OK this definitely won't work
    , @lang = 'us_english'
    , @replace = 'replace'
    GO

DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(2048) = FORMATMESSAGE(60001, 'test1' ); 

THROW 60001, @msg, 1; 
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addmessage
      @msgnum   = 60001
    , @severity = 16
    , @msgtext  = N'Even if you escape it, the sign  %%  disappears...' -- Even if you escape it
    , @lang = 'us_english'
    , @replace = 'replace'
    GO

DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(2048) = FORMATMESSAGE(60001, 'test1' ); 

THROW 60001, @msg, 1; 
GO


EXEC sys.sp_addmessage
      @msgnum   = 60001
    , @severity = 16
    , @msgtext  = N'I am 100 percent sure this will work.'
    , @lang = 'us_english'
    , @replace = 'replace'
GO

DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(2048) = FORMATMESSAGE(60001, 'test1' ); 

THROW 60001, @msg, 1;
GO


-- Tidy up
EXEC sys.sp_dropmessage 60001
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, very clean, way would be to create a variable e.g.:

```
declare @PctChar char(1) = '%'
```

then use that variable in `formatmessage` or `raiserror`, as:

```
raiserror('98%s',0,1,@PctChar);
```